# Query to get connection list from two tables named user and connection

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

User table:

userid  | first_name  | last_name |email         |Password

```
1    | Tom        | cruise    |tom@gmail.com |d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
2    | Tamera     | Manzer    |Tame@yahoo.com|d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
3    | Vergie     | Manzer    |Vere@live.com |d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
4    | Elmo       | Milano    |elmo@live.com |d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Connection Table

con_id  | userid    | connected_with |date

```
1    | 1        | 2    |2015-04-26
2    | 1        | 3    |2015-04-26
3    | 4        | 1    |2015-04-26
```

I want to make query to find connection of userid 1. In this 1 userid is connected with 2, 3, and also 4 so how can I find connection of userid 1

Comment: Start with learning mysql queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your answer from here.

[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407277/how-do-i-do-select-from-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-codeigniter)

MySql Query.

```
SELECT Connection.connected_with, Connection.date
FROM Connection
JOIN User ON User.userid = Connection.userid
WHERE Connection.userid =1
```

Codeigniter Active Record

```
$this->db->select('connected_with', 'date');
$this->db->from('Connection');
$this->db->join('User', 'User.userid' = 'Connection.userid');
$this->db->where('userid', 1);
$this->db->get();
```

Like you said in comment, you have two foreign keys `userid` & `connected_with`, you can use union to combine both query result. First query you find the connection where `Connection.userid=1`. Second query you find the connection where `Connection.connected_with=1`. Then combine both result.

See the code below

```
SELECT Connection.userid AS 'Connection'
FROM Connection
JOIN User ON User.userid = Connection.connected_with
WHERE Connection.connected_with =1
UNION
SELECT Connection.connected_with
FROM Connection
JOIN User ON User.userid = Connection.userid
WHERE Connection.userid =1
```

Codeigniter Active Record

```
// First Query
$this->db->select('connected_with', 'date');
$this->db->from('Connection');
$this->db->join('User', 'User.userid' = 'Connection.userid');
$this->db->where('userid', 1);
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$subQuery1 = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();

// Second Query
$this->db->select('userid', 'date');
$this->db->from('Connection');
$this->db->join('User', 'User.userid' = 'Connection.connected_with);
$this->db->where('connected_with', 1);
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$subQuery2 = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();

// Union
$this->db->from("($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2)");
$this->db->get();
```

Output

```
+--------------------------+
| Connection for User ID 1 |
+--------------------------+
|                        4 |
|                        2 |
|                        3 |
+--------------------------+
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: In this query I did not get record #3 of Connection Table because it is also connected with userid 1 @Thomas Kilian

Comment: any one can help me
Actually here is 2 same foreign keys so I have so I have problem to get record #3 of Connection Table because it is also connected with userid 1

Comment: See my post. I already edit it to include answer like you want.